# Label equation with a symbol

Tags: symbols, equations, cross-referencing

I would like to label an equation with an arbitrary symbol, rather than a number, or letter.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Perhaps something like this.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}   % loads »amsmath«

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}\label{eqn:einstein}
    E=mc^2\tag{*}
  \end{equation}
  \eqref{eqn:einstein}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Tagging appears not to work when the equation is displayed with `\displaymath`. Is there a strategy that works in this case?

Comment: `\tag{$*$}` looks better to me

Comment: Why do you need both label and tag? 
What's the difference?

Comment: @skan Label is how you refer to it using references later in the document, tag tells latex how you want the reference to look like (what symbol to use)

Comment: `\tag` doesn't work with the `eqnarray` environment. Is there a similar command that does?

Answer (score 96):

With [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), you have two similar commands:

- `\tag{label}` where label can be any text or symbol. Note, for most symbol mathmode is required, for example: `\tag{$\star$}`. Here the label would be typeset within parentheses.
- `\tag*{label}`, in contrast, does not add parentheses, otherwise it works similar to `\tag`.

For further information have a look at the [amsmath user's guide](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf).

Answer (score 54):

In addition to the answers about how to `\tag` equations with symbols, there are a number of packages that give you access to a bunch more symbols. Like `pifont`, `ifsym`, `MarvoSym`, `bbding` See p. 71 *et seq.* of the [Comprehensive LaTeX symbols list](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) for details.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
E=mc^2 \label{eq:einstein} \tag{\ding{37}}
\]
As we can see from \eqref{eq:einstein}\ldots
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: pifont image]