# How to label an optimization problem with a label such as (P)?

Tags: equations, labels

I am trying to write an optimization problem in my document, and for convenience, to define a label to refer to it.  I don't want to refer to it as equation (3), which I know how to do, I want to define a special text label for it, see below for an example.

```
       max  \sum p_t s_t
(P)    s.t. s_t \leq d_t
            \sum s_t \leq I
```

Is there a way to put the label on the right side if I so desire?  For example,

```
max  \sum p_t s_t
s.t. s_t \leq d_t    (P)
\sum s_t \leq I
```

Comment: The first part of your question is answered in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12026/label-equation-with-a-symbol

Comment: I think the labels are on the right by default. Are you doing something to make them go to the left?

Comment: @Caramdir: Yes, they are on the right by default. Setting them to the left can by done by the `leqno` package option: `\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}`. But that will then hold for all equations.

Comment: `\[ f(x) = y \eqno{(P)} \]` will put (P) on the right even with `leqno`, but it's not a true tag, and can't be referred back to with `\ref` (AFAIK).

Comment: Thank you for your answers! That definitely answers my questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this will give you the tag and xref you want.  you'll probably want to adjust the alignment, but that's not what the question was about.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

We want to refer to an optimization problem \eqref{opt-P} with a
non-numeric tag.
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \max \sum p_t s_t\\
& \text{s.t. } s_t \leq d_t\\
& \sum s_t \leq I
\end{aligned}
\tag{P}\label{opt-P}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

if you're using `amsmath` (as this example does) and the tags are usually on the left, then add this to the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\onetagright}{\tagsleft@false}
\makeatother
```

wrap the equation in `\begingroup \onetagright ... \endgroup` and just that one tag goes on the right.

Answer (score 3):

`\[ f(x) = y \eqno{(P)} \]` will put (P) on the right even with `leqno`, but it's not a true tag, and can't be referred back to with `\ref` (AFAIK).

Comment: I'm out of votes, but your answer *will* receive an upvote tomorrow.

Comment: The braces should be unnecessary, as everything from `\eqno` to the first `$` (with expansion, so `\]` will end it) is the "equation number" and it's definitely *not* a command with an argument. Maybe `\eqno\textup{(P)}` would be better, since the equation number is typeset in math mode.