# Multiple labels in aligned environment

Tags: cross-referencing, amsmath, align

I would like to format an optimization problem by

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

We want to label each line separately. The inserted text and formulas
have to be aligned like in this example:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\label{eq:3}
& \underset{X}{\text{minimize}} & &  \mathrm{trace}(X) \\
& \text{subject to} &&  X_{ij} = M_{ij}, \; (i,j) \in \Omega, \\
& &&  X \succeq 0. 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Already described in [How to label an optimization problem with a label such as (P)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25246/how-to-label-an-optimization-problem-with-a-label-such-as-p)).

An ideal alignment of the inserted text and formulas is achieved by the `aligned` environment. However, I want to label each line separately. By placing `\label{...}` at each line

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{X}{\text{minimize}} & &  \mathrm{trace}(X) \label{eq:6}\\
& \text{subject to} &&  X_{ij} = M_{ij}, \; (i,j) \in \Omega, \label{eq:7} \\
& &&  X \succeq 0. \label{eq:9} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

I get the error message: "Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'eq:4' will be lost."

How can I label each line individually?

Comment: Using `align` environment instead of `equation` and `aligned` will work: `\begin{align}
& \max \sum p_t s_t \label{eq:3}\& \text{s.t. } s_t \leq d_t \label{eq:4}\& \sum s_t \leq I \label{eq:5}
\end{align}`

Comment: I need the tighter alignment provided by the aligned environment. The original example did not show the relevant point, so I inserted another example.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Only one label is possible within the `equation` environment. However, multiple labels are possible within an `align` environment. In your case, as in many other, using an `align` is preferable to using an `aligned` inside an `equation`. Moreover, the `subequations` environment lends itself well to your problem.

Additional note: in math mode, it's good practice to put a thin space (`\,`) before punctuation marks (such as full stops and commas), so that the reader does not confuse them as part of the math quantities they precede.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

We want to label each line separately. The inserted text and formulas
have to be aligned like in this example:
\begin{subequations}
\label{eq:optim}
\begin{align}
    \underset{X}{\text{minimize}}
        & \quad \mathrm{trace}(X)   \label{eq:cost}\\
    \text{subject to} 
        & \quad X_{ij} = M_{ij}\,, \; (i,j) \in \Omega\,, \label{eq:const1}\\
        & \quad X \succeq 0 \,. \label{eq:const2}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

Equation \ref{eq:cost} is the cost and Equations \ref{eq:const1} and \ref{eq:const2}
are the constraints of optimisation problem \ref{eq:optim}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is another approach with `alignat` which is more closely to the origonal formatting: `\begin{alignat}{2}
    &\underset{X}{\text{minimize}} \quad& &\mathrm{trace}(X)   \label{eq:cost}\    &\text{subject to} &  &X_{ij} = M_{ij}\,, \; (i,j) \in
    \Omega\,, \label{eq:const1}\    & & &X \succeq 0 \,. \label{eq:const2}
\end{alignat}`