# fleqn and \eqno together?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, labels

It seems that I can not use together

- **fleqn** option [to move the equations to the left] and
- **\leqno** [to give a hand-made label to equations].

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno,fleqn]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \sin^x + \cos^2x = 1
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The equation number is on the left and the equation is left aligned for all display mode equations.

If you don't want **all** equations left aligned, then ydon't add the package option `[fleqn]` and use `flalign` for the ones you want left aligned as follows (note the `&&` at the end):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \sin^x + \cos^2x = 1
\end{align}
\begin{flalign}
    \sin^x + \cos^2x = 1 &&
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Just saw the reference to *hand-made* labels in your question.  If by this you mean custom labels, then you can adapt the solution from [Label equation with a symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12026/label-equation-with-a-symbol) as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1  \tag{\ding{37}}
\end{align}
\begin{flalign}
    \sin^x + \cos^2x = 1 \tag{\ding{37}} &&
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great :) --- I just found that \tag* produce a tag without parentheses.