# Custom Equation Numbering

Tags: math-mode, equations, numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Label equation with a symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12026/label-equation-with-a-symbol)

I wanted to know if there a way to create your own custom markings for equation numbering instead of the automatic numbering. Preferably, I would like it to be flexible to the point where I could name the equation with almost any command such as `\dagger` or `\Faxmachine`. I know those are pretty silly, but just wanted to emphasis that I did not want to just have custom numbering such as `{1,3,5,...} or {1.1,1.2,1.3,...}, etc`. I may want a symbol say `star`. No specific environment is acquired.

Comment: `\tag{\dagger}`?

Comment: What does that do? How do you place it, right after the equation? Can you provide a `MWE` please, could be just a one line equation to exemplify the use of it.

Comment: Have a look at [Label equation with a symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12026/label-equation-with-a-symbol), there's also a MWE, and please tell us if that helped. We would close this question as a duplicate then.

Comment: Yes it did the job. Thanks Stefan. This can be closed now.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz: How can you make symbols large such as `\star`?

Comment: @nightowl Such as `\tag{{\Large$\star$}}` Btw., in general, if you got a new or followup question, just open a new question. You know, it's a Q&A site, not a forum. ;-)

Comment: @nightowl Sorry, I was a bit lazy, I could have provided some more context.

Comment: Okay Thanks. I will keep that in mind for now on. `:)`

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: That's okay. If I had familiarity with what you was referring to that would of been enough, but I didn't. I don't use `tags` often.