# Displaying formula with a star

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting

I want to display a centered formula to which can be referred as (*). Now, I  have the following: [image]

But I want the formula to be more centered and the star to be right aligned. The code is now:

```
$$
    \floor{7(n\pi - \floor{n\pi})}  \qquad \qquad (*)
$$
```

Comment: Red from my lips: Don't use `$$...$$` ... it's deprecated. Use `\[...\]` ... which is robust meanwhile since TL2015

Comment: Okay, thank you. Did not knew that.

Comment: some relevant information here: [Label equation with a symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12026/579)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a choice between a six-pointed asterisk, generated by `\ast`, and a five-pointed asterisk, generated by `\star`. Both of these macros need to be used in math-mode; choose whichever symbol you like better.

I would also enlarge the floor-related symbols of the "outer" `\floor` directive slightly as a visual aid towards parsing the equation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \DeclarePairedDelimiter macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\floor}{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\setlength\textwidth{5cm} % just for this example
\begin{document}
either
\[
\floor[\big]{7(n\pi - \floor{n\pi})}  \tag{$\star$}
\]

or

\[
\floor[\big]{7(n\pi - \floor{n\pi})}  \tag{$\ast$}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `\tag{\textasteriskcentered}` command to provide for a `(*)` equation 'number', either in `align*` or in `align` environment, `equation` would do too.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\floor}{\lfloor}{\rfloor}


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \floor{7\mleft(n\pi - \floor{n\pi}\mright)}  \tag{\textasteriskcentered} \label{flooreq}
\end{align*}

In \eqref{flooreq} we see that 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since there doesn't seem to be anything to be aligned, I wouldn't use an `align` or `align*` environment in this case.

Comment: @Mico: Well, yes, but I doubt that the floor stuff will just be put alone -- it's a term, but not an equation. Of, course `\[...\]` would be nice too.