# Custom numbering of Equations

Tags: equations, numbering

Hi i am having a problem making a custom tag for this equation

```
\begin{equation*}\label{eq:3}
        C_1 = \theta \left(Y_1^L -T_1+\frac{1}{1+r}(Y_2^L+T_2)+V_1\right) \tag(3)
    \end{equation*}
```

I want to refer to an equation from a book (as part of my class) which i called equation 3. But i simply can't change it without getting a lot of syntax errors.

I have tryed different things form the forum, but so far without luck.

Hope you can help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Use `equation` without a star.

Comment: I think [Label equation with a symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12026/106162) covers what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Just eliminate those stars coming after equations *. This is true fact in most cases of latex. With putting some star, you may present your equations without having numbers or tags.

Comment: Can you maybe expand you nswer a bit? Bernard already adviced that in the comments and we like answers to be a tiny bit more verbose.